# Content Security Policy not allowing form submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, google-chrome, content-security-policy

Please I need assistance here.
I have a form to submit to another url but when I try to submit it, it refuses to submit and I was checking my console.

On Chrome, I see the following errors

> resources2.aspx?HCCID=75694719&culture=en-US&mlcv=3006&template=5:7 Refused to load the image 'https://s4.mylivechat.com/livechat2/images/sprite.png' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "img-src 'self' data:".
>
> Refused to send form data to 'https://cipg.stanbicibtcbank.com/MerchantServices/MakePayment.aspx' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "form-action 'self'".

and on Mozilla Firefox I see the following:

> Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at https://s4.mylivechat.com/livechat2/images/sprite.png (“img-src http://smehelp.themarketplace.ng data:”)
>
> Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at http://smehelp.themarketplace.ng/purchase/summary (“form-action 'self'”).

Checking around the web for solution, I have added the following to my page header

```
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="form-action 'self'">
```

but the problem still persists.

This results in the fact that I am not able to submit my forms. Earlier, the forms used to get submitted, but I just tried it today and observed this error.

I am running on Google Chrome Version 55.0.2883.95 (64-bit) on a MAC OS.

I will appreciate any suggestion to solve this issue as soon as possible.

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are passing the `Content-Security-Policy` value in your response header:

> base-uri 'none'; default-src 'self' https://s4.mylivechat.com;
>   child-src 'none'; connect-src 'self'; font-src 'self'
>   https://fonts.googleapis.com https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com
>   https://fonts.gstatic.com; form-action 'self'; frame-ancestors 'none';
>   img-src 'self' data:; media-src 'self'; object-src 'none'; script-src
>   'self' https://www.youtube.com https://maps.google.com
>   https://www.google-analytics.com https://mylivechat.com
>   https://s4.mylivechat.com https://maps.googleapis.com 'unsafe-inline'
>   'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' https://fonts.googleapis.com
>   https://s4.mylivechat.com https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com
>   'unsafe-inline'

The content security policy that you've added to the page meta will be ignored as this is present in the response header.

You will need to make the following additions (in bold) to your CSP that you are sending in your response header.

> base-uri 'none'; default-src 'self' https://s4.mylivechat.com;
>   child-src 'none'; connect-src 'self'; font-src 'self'
>   https://fonts.googleapis.com https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com
>   https://fonts.gstatic.com; form-action 'self'
>   **https://cipg.stanbicibtcbank.com/MerchantServices/MakePayment.aspx**; frame-ancestors 'none'; img-src 'self' data:
>   **https://s4.mylivechat.com**; media-src 'self'; object-src 'none'; script-src 'self' https://www.youtube.com https://maps.google.com
>   https://www.google-analytics.com https://mylivechat.com
>   https://s4.mylivechat.com https://maps.googleapis.com 'unsafe-inline'
>   'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' https://fonts.googleapis.com
>   https://s4.mylivechat.com https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com
>   'unsafe-inline';

- Add https://s4.mylivechat.com to img-src
- Add https://cipg.stanbicibtcbank.com/MerchantServices/MakePayment.aspx to form-action
- Remove `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="form-action 'self'">` from your HTML code

Comment: Thank you for your response. Please could you show me how to "Add https://cipg.stanbicibtcbank.com/MerchantServices/MakePayment.aspx to form-action" and "Add https://s4.mylivechat.com to img-src" because this would be my first time implementing Content-Security-Policy. Thank you

Comment: Your site is already sending Content-Security-Policy headers in the response. You would need to edit the code that is generating that policy. If it isn't generated by your application server, your webserver may have been configured to send this value.

Comment: Ok. Any guide as to where and how to modify the headers? Forgive my naivity

Comment: It would depend on which piece of your stack is sending the header. If you are the sole maintainer of your site, I'd start by looking at yoir webserver configuration file(s) or run a full text search for something CSP specific such as "connect-src" in your codebase.

Comment: Ok. Would it be possible to rather overwrite the headers instead of editing the one already being sent? So that I dont have to modify the one already set

Answer (score 7):

If you look here because you want to send a form to the same URL (which should be possible with `form-action 'self'`) or another URL listed in your `form-action` rule, but redirect afterwards, the following could be the cause https://github.com/w3c/webappsec-csp/issues/8 (including a long discussion). One reason is: https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Unvalidated_Redirects_and_Forwards_Cheat_Sheet.html

The reason why the target url of the redirect is not visible in the CSP report (which is really confusing) is a security issue, see https://w3c.github.io/webappsec-csp/#create-violation-for-request, it would otherwise be possible to analyse the behaviour of form endpoints.

**tl:dr;**
Chrome and Safari do not allow redirects after submitting a form unless the destination URL is listed in the form-action CSP rule, even if it is a GET redirect that does not contain the original form data.