# Redirect Page After Submit Form in CodeIgniter 4 Cannot Work

Tags: php, codeigniter, content-security-policy, codeigniter-4

I have a problem when submitting a form, the redirect() function in Codeigniter 4 doesn't work on Chrome browser. but when tried in mozilla firefox browser the redirect() function works. error that is displayed on the console as below:

> Refused to send form data to "https://..............." because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "form-action 'self'".

Function used:

> return redirect()->to("/home");

additional case, when I try to access by using IP or not with the domain. this function can work. why?

Comment: read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41942834/content-security-policy-not-allowing-form-submission

Answer (score 0):

When you restrict form-action in your content-security-policy but only allow 'self' . You need to include all hosts that may be included in the redirect chain after the post.